# How to properly type this typescript generic function

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Given the example below:

```js
const brands = { mercedes: "mercedes", audi: "audi" } as const;
type Brands = keyof typeof brands;

type MercedesFactory = {
    propA: string;
}

type AudiFactory = {
    propB: string;
}

type CarProps<TFactory> = {
    color: string;
    hp: number;
    factory: TFactory
}

type Mercedes = {
    c180: CarProps<MercedesFactory>,
    c220: CarProps<MercedesFactory>,
}

type Audi = {
    a3: CarProps<AudiFactory>,
    tt: CarProps<AudiFactory>,
}

const mercedes: Mercedes = {
    c180:
    {
        color: "blue",
        hp: 120,
        factory: { propA: "xx" }
    },
    c220: {
        color: "black",
        hp: 150,
        factory: { propA: "yy" }
    }
}

const audi: Audi = {
    a3:
    {
        color: "blue",
        hp: 120,
        factory: { propB: "zz" }
    },
    tt: {
        color: "red",
        hp: 150,
        factory: { propB: "aa" }
    }
}

const allCars: Record<Brands, Mercedes | Audi> = {
    mercedes,
    audi,
}
```

I want the generic function bellow to return Fabric information for all the blue cars, depends on the brand passed as parameter:

```js
const getAllBlueCars = (brand: Brands) => {
    const carBrand = allCars[brand]; // Mercedes | Audi
    // object car is not typed correctly (any), and function returns any[]
    return Object.values(carBrand).reduce((acc, car) => {
        if (car.color === "blue") {
            return [...acc, car.factory];
        }
        return acc;
    }, [])
    // I'd like car is typed correctly and function returns an MercedesFactory[] or AudiFactory[], depends on which brand was passed like the example bellow
}
```

But as you can see below, it's returning any;

```js
const allAudiBlueCarsFabric = getAllBlueCars("audi"); // any
```

This works fine, car is typed correctly and it returns correct type:

```js
const mercedesFactories = Object.values(mercedes).reduce<MercedesFactory[]>((acc, car) => (car.color === "blue" ? [...acc, car.factory] : acc), []);

// another simple example, using filter
const carMercedesFilterExample = Object.values(mercedes).filter((car) => car.color === "blue");
```

> **[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgJwIZgCYRgXhgbxgWwFMFhDVCIAuGAIiJLIpoBoYkBXVAS2po+5owAvmwyhIUANwAoKAE8ADoRgAhZGgzYA1oTkgAZjHlKD8dehmzFygLLFS5CADEkwKCARysuaTD8wFBBAFAEFqaAQuMABzGSFpKyUYEM4uFzcPL2wcX39A4JVwqEiYuITjZQBhJAQABSCFCAAeABV0908APm8c-xhQABsPIpLY3L8ACwVqMHZ8OGIZPv1XDrlqNtXM6XjE23tGTR8+4ABGAA4ABmpquobmuwZHdszO5nH+gCZP65hb+uCDwOzy2XXeuwqyVSPQ+SAAzDcagDGk0UtwXmCPlAoIi7oDUakMXI3jsEuJoARgRRqI8HBQYScLtcPr0+v5BsNaHABuxCCwPn0ptRTj93mz-CsMp5qHh8qFeAAPBWCeJ9IRi9nfX6s8UchC8bmuLT88WTaYwU4AVkuGvFkrWMoCDTCtDkchVH3iu3JsH4PCh3AZ-nhlBZAvZICG+q5PL5trZQotovDfntmUdcsKtAAXtmPWr49iZSn+pHOTQEGQTabE1abSW09LcE6CrwkEh8-4vWTwBSkAMBrcqDAAEqEUAIVBNNQodCsWmHGAAHwDXG62Q+9DpEHjfvBCQA9AejBMuBgIBMQOwBqh4MokDBooQwMQuMAYPp2GA3FxwCekLAlZQOwCBgDALiIG+MBRPoHj4ABv5gbBCBsAOJ7KNyvL9DUO4wOQSgaDAf5QBMGHmAESAQBAZDSD6j6EFAIQDiosZDt4AAUiCztQM4aAAlFg3Q6qWEjYQgvG3tg-aDjhADaXFoAAupIMBHjAC6OMuq4fGpIBwAAVuOsDADU0EYGAICwBUt4TpWbgDF47EoHIfGsLOH5fj+f5ASBkBsGAciyYpHw+aBMAAPIGUZAB0ABu-a8hA7EmeJ5h8dFlaoOwpDsU5wDAKwKUCZgQkllwhjJTU0V6lgmDYDQmF8gJwmmjAoVgbJ0Vda4BVidFjZyMpJaqqa7VsPlSxdqwQV8Tpx4AJIAOS3gMXA6GJZlGNYNkeHZUAOf5qCft+UCIW1DG+RgKDqVSzigoFilEShaJpPdQWsPhz7oERYEAO6nsAExmO5v2URRVFkDAq3rSRyiEAqSD4AoAwYYQA4gL9pK0b2voDi9LG8kOEGRO+2BPoxzGsTh7F8KkNB8SpanOYex4kWeMC-R4WgYPoUSEIVpns9ZpYIHtDnY6JW6HBiXD0tgkWGW4cUJRQ7FS446WZdlhBNBpFBEkFnS5T1AsIMV3SVQg1VlihdX1Y1ggAPwwJ13X5ab-X3Y91A9a5LuKQz0hMxZsMoRAXBIyjMDw4jyP8zA7DhzEH5cAMUDEBLFIpXrzip+nCAAKII5Hyjy1FSvxbGSXqxQ6W82nxC5UVgl9TVdsxry9OWAkPdB8eLQABLzQAyjAI8wIPBd-APIQtDAADitRz8P4UADIAKotPN4UAHIwAAtIfR-Hyfp9n+fF+X1f1837fN89qJ5NMQMBOEEOnzeK0EnRwq6eERJEAjYKVQBsCS5tjgRlEilb+UkBxDnkuYIac1oKwE5ggbmrA4DsGMoLc8p00LCzBszPoY0FYxUrolS2YCMpkG1k0XKLRv7wz-t9Ogt0nY3SePre6MBqAvSJHxGaRs8q9WbiVCB4pyowEttbKMtV7axnphI1q51gJhVdtFE2fUBpDVaiNcUY0eqTT8Oqf2gchCWDotJfGVMEB3UgsAD+ZMGLP1fu-Gmfou5AA)**

---

This is the Chat GPT Solution. The returned value is correct, but car is still typed wrong:

```js
const getAllBlueCars2 = <TBrand extends Brands>(brand: TBrand) => {
    const carBrand = allCars[brand];

    // it works, but car is still typed as any
    return Object.values(carBrand).reduce<((TBrand extends "mercedes" ? MercedesFactory : AudiFactory)[])>((acc, car) => {
        if (car.color === "blue") {
            return [...acc, car.factory];
        }
        return acc;
    }, []);
};

const allAudiBlueCarsFabric2 = getAllBlueCars2("audi"); // AudiFactory[]
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mZv2Pm) using the technique described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, despite not being the cleanest solution, it works pretty well. Fell free to post an official answer so I can mark it as solution and upvote your post.

Comment: I will post one if I think it’s better than your solution in some way… but it might not be until tomorrow when I can get to a real computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `allCars` value doesn't have a strongly typed relationship between the keys and values:

```
const allCars: Record<Brands, Mercedes | Audi> = {
    mercedes,
    audi,
}
```

Since you [annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) as `Record<Brands, Mercedes | Audi>`, then it could possibly be a value like `{mercedes: audi, audi: mercedes}`.  If you want better typings, you'll need to give it a stronger type like `{mercedes: Mercedes, audi: Audi}`, which is what the compiler infers if you don't annotate at all:

```
const allCars = {
    mercedes,
    audi,
};
// const allCars: {mercedes: Mercedes; audi: Audi};
type AllCars = typeof allCars;
```

Still, even if you do that, the compiler can't follow the logic:

```
const getAllBlueCars = <K extends Brands>(brand: K) => {
    const carBrand = allCars[brand]; //  AllCars[K]
    const carPropsArray = Object.values(carBrand); // any[]
    return carPropsArray.reduce((acc, car) => {
        if (car.color === "blue") {
            return [...acc, car.factory];
        }
        return acc;
    }, []);
}

const allAudiBlueCarsFabric = getAllBlueCars("audi"); // any
```

The `carPropsArray` value is inferred as having type `any[]`.  The compiler doesn't understand that `Object.values(AllCars[K])` should also be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `K`.  The correlation between `brand` and `carPropsArray` has been lost.

Of course you can just annotate `carPropsArray` as any array type you want, since [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) is loose enough to permit even crazy things (e.g., `const carPropsArray: number[] = Object.values(carBrand);` would be accepted), but you're not getting the compiler to compute the correct types for you.

---

The only way I know of to get it the correlation between `brand` and `carPropsArray` to be computed by the compiler is to refactor your types using the technique described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  Essentially you need to express `carBrands` as a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over some underlying base type, and then [index into it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with the generic type `K` to get another generic type out.

The way I usually do this is to rename the original object out of the way

```
const _allCars = {
    mercedes,
    audi,
}    
type _AllCars = typeof _allCars;
```

and then use it to compute the related base type:

```
type CarFactories = { [K in Brands]: 
  _AllCars[K][keyof _AllCars[K]] extends CarProps<infer F> ? F : never 
}

/* type CarFactories = {
  mercedes: MercedesFactory;
  audi: AudiFactory;
} */
```

and then rebuild the original type as a mapped type over the base type:

```
type AllCars = { [K in Brands]: Record<string, CarProps<CarFactories[K]>> };
```

and assign the original object to the new value annotated with the new type:

```
const allCars: AllCars = _allCars;
```

On the face of it this doesn't look like anything much has changed, but now the compiler sees an explicit relationship between `AllCars[K]` and `Record<string, CarProps<CarFactories[K]>>.

And the implementation of `getAllBlueCars` suddenly becomes a lot more strongly typed:

```
const getAllBlueCars = <K extends Brands>(brand: K) => {

    const carBrand = allCars[brand]; //  AllCars[K]
    const carPropsArray = Object.values(carBrand); // CarProps<CarFactories[K]>[]
    return carPropsArray.reduce<CarFactories[K][]>((acc, car) => {
        if (car.color === "blue") {
            return [...acc, car.factory];
        }
        return acc;
    }, [])
}
```

Here, `carPropsArray` is seen as type `CarProps<CarFactories[K]>[]`, and thus when we `reduce()` that array with an initial value of type `CarFactories[K][]`, the compiler understands that the implementation is safe, and that the return value is of that generic type.  So the type of `getAllBlueCars` is `<K extends Brands>(brand: K) => CarFactories[K][]`

Which means when we call it, we get the strongly-typed output you expect:

```
const allAudiBlueCarsFabric = getAllBlueCars("audi"); // AudiFactory[]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgJwIZgCYRgXhgbxgWwFMFhDVCIAuGAIiJLIpoBoYkBXVAS2po+5owAvmwyhIUANwAoKAE8ADoRgAhZGgzYA1oTkgAZjHlKD8dehmzFygLLFS5CADEkwKCARysuGAoQgFAEFqaAQuMABzSWErJRhAzi4XNw8vbDw-AJUQqDDI6KFpWOUAYSQEAAV-BQgAHicAPm8caRg2mFAAGw8cvKjW9oALBWowdnw4Yhl2mH1Xd09qJ2lCouNbe0ZNXAG24ABGAA4ABmoyyuq6uwZHZIW5BuZdjoAmF9OYc6qAq83b+dSjxWa2s8USzWeSAAzGdyt8arUEtw7oCnjMoFBYRcfojEijPEDVuJoAQ-hRqNcHBQITMDidKM8WjNaSBugheHBOuxCCxnjNhtR9u80cy2nMUosfJkgrwAB6ywSFGZCEV7N4fJmijqsnq0TmuLS8rUwAUwfYAVmOquZ4vu1Ay1WCtDkckVz0KRPAJP4PDB3Bp7WhDJmmtFXV1NE53KNWtNQqtfPattS9t81WytAAXpm3crrRj7Ym9jr2bQEGQY6K45brTNk5KHVleEgkLn2h6imAkEQIApXMoAMoeKAAeUMLWexNgSE6nXO21DzPoVIgtcDiWtQmm7QA9DvtRI2LP5-bl1sKWSINEfdQkVwt891vFj+VtutTDO56-LCzDxFCFAgSzioXKEPO3i1AA0jAhCylAhAaKo5gQA0AAUiAoKg1CQQAlFgTSLr+JLAOUaiYd4n7zgA2hhaAALrRHubRAV+CAQFRkF0UWB7EXClyBAgyBpDAI5wAAVoQbgAHQAG4ztyECoSRCBkWgOGMfuKByFRXHGuWUDsAgYAdHxPwCUJUnlqg7CkKhqGuMArDKXhmAEdxMxcIYSnlFJ4YIFgmDYJGoE0HhhHGu0+mGcZVFSXFDlOT59ZyAx7ntmlbRRUZbDAMA26iiqMA6ep7pFER06zneIHcvOLiIFwwDeP+gHAaB86oXwiShRpbBgHIRSrF2PZ9qQMBOFwso7JOXqwAA+pRr4BqKZ6OGubQ+puZXtE+s0seB2DvoY80vmx+VGKC5z4lw1LpEV0HhEhmEQHR1C7Sd7GcVROh6Ede2vhxdF0TBcEIegnymQi4T6MQY1NAA-GNMCjIQMkw0qu4AFTnXEl0AmEN07Mtl4XjcFD4nIZ3rYkt54njFPujAGM7ltbRPn9bHNHdMAPap6AvTAABKkkeKgtShOEESsF8ly1LjErXR9dENE06PFoeC1sbe73eMdrFXizPGwM1LHVWBi3YFBwPwYhvMoeh5jYS5bncVOJkqeYFHvTR5gMTATHPnrAMuzNbvwhA5lIMJokSdJcmgYpym8+pfv7tLOJywsCsAw0OncVlxnKWHEdyJZZA2YQsvlFdFAAzpaH2bliUIE7hMRW0nkwN5CC+SWAVBVGPJhRlzL50VcVSQlbtSclqVt20qsRaPDmU+2rDFaV03q5ViSm7VSD1Y12DG61NWvh1PrdSnfpJHTudFPfA1AA)

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest solution I could find.

```js
// Modified the ChatGPT version
const getAllBlueCars2 = <T extends Brands>(brand: T) => {
  type ArrType = CarProps<MercedesFactory | AudiFactory>
  const carBrand = allCars[brand];
  const cars: ArrType[] = Object.values(carBrand)

  return cars.reduce<ArrType['factory'][]>((acc, car) => {
    if (car.color === "blue") {
      return [...acc, car.factory];
    }
    return acc;
  }, []) as (T extends "mercedes" ? MercedesFactory : AudiFactory)[];
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately this way I lost acc type , and the function returns `ArrType[]`type instead `AudiFactory[]`

Answer (score 0):

After some hours digging into, I also found myself an acceptable solution.

```js
type Factory<T extends Brands> = T extends "mercedes" ? MercedesFactory : T extends "audi" ? AudiFactory : never;

const getAllBlueCars2 = <T extends Brands>(brand: T) => {
  const carBrand = allCars[brand];
  const cars: CarProps<Factory<T>>[] = Object.values(carBrand)

  return Object.values(cars).reduce<Factory<T>[]>((acc, car) => {
    if (car.color === "blue") {
      return [...acc, car.factory];
    }
    return acc;
  }, [])
}

const allAudiBlueCarsFabric2 = getAllBlueCars2("mercedes");
```

Comment: This answer isn't particularly type safe as `Object.vaues(carBrand)`'s returns `any[]` for your `carBrand`.  (So you could also write `const cars: number[] = Object.values(carBrand)` and the compiler wouldn't complain). It's equivalent to a [type assertion](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) like `const cars = Object.values(carBrand) as CarProps<Factory<T>>[]`.  If you're okay with that, great (but it should be noted in the answer).  If you want something more type safe where the compiler *would* complain, I can post my answer. Let me know.

Comment: I will be glad if you can post a more type safety solution.